# Quotient Space of $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1] $

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

The Quotient space of $X=\mathbb{R}\times [0,1] $ is defined by the equivalence relation $(x,t) \sim(x+1,t)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

I need to prove that the space $X/\sim$ is a Hausdorff and compact space.

Comment: What do you mean by your definition of $q$?
You can't map one point $(x,y)$ to two points?

Comment: Just to make sure: have you got a picture of what $X/~$ should "look like" in mind?

Comment: Hint: note that the map $X\to S^1\times[0,1]$ prescribed by $\langle x,t\rangle\mapsto\langle\langle\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x\rangle,t\rangle$ respects the quotient map.

Comment: It's infinite copies of S^1

Comment: It's a cylinder with height and radius 1

Comment: It is indeed a cylinder. Can you prove that properly?

Comment: We can identify each equivalence class by $[0,t]$ and we map these equivalence class to $S^1 \times t $.